# Redirect all sub-directories but not parent

Tags: regex, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect all folders after a subdirectory:

```
example.com/sub/sub2/some-place
example.com/sub/sub3/some-place
example.com/sub/subY/some-place
```

to a subdomain:

```
sub.example.com/sub2/some-place
sub.example.com/sub3/some-place
sub.example.com/subY/some-place
```

This is the rule I'm using and it works:

```
RewriteRule ^sub/(.*)$ http://sub.example.com/$1 [R=302,L]
```

However, I don't want the example.com/sub/ directory to be redirected.

User visits example.com/sub/ should stay at /sub/
User visits example.com/sub/ANYTHINGELSE should be redirected to sub.example.com/ANYTHGINELSE

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Question: How do I add an exclusion to the rule? Example: I want

```
example.com/sub/sub2/some-place 
example.com/sub/sub3/some-place 
example.com/sub/subY/some-place
```

to redirect as above but

```
example.com/sub/thispageshouldnotredirect
```

to NOT redirect. I tried adding this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/thispageshouldnotredirect
```

EDIT #2: This is working for me currently:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sub/thispageshouldnotredirect/?$
RewriteRule ^sub/(.+)$ http://sub.example.com/$1 [R=302,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.+` in place of `.*` to make sure there are 1 more characters after `/sub/`:

```
RewriteRule ^sub/(.+)$ http://sub.example.com/$1 [R=302,L]
```

Comment: this is working great appreciate it. Question: How do I add an exclusion to the rule? Example: I want
    example.com/sub/sub2/some-place
    example.com/sub/sub3/some-place
    example.com/sub/subY/some-place
 to redirect as above but 
` example.com/sub/thispageshouldnotredirect to NOT redirect. 
I tried adding this rule:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/thispageshouldnotredirect

Comment: Oh I missed your previous comment. Difficult to read that long comment. Can you edit the question and explain this new requirement clearly so that I can edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Edited question and answered my 2nd question. Can you confirm this is correct / is there a better implementation? Thanks!

Comment: With the slight change `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sub/thispageshouldnotredirect(/|$)` is the correct condition which will ignore everything starting with `/sub/thispageshouldnotredirect` from this redirect.

Comment: Appreciate it. Do you have any links to resources where I can learn more about this kind of stuff? Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: You're most welcome. I only use http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html for reference. But lot of things I learnt on SO itself from other answers.